# Unable to upgrade windows 8.1 to 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade, dism

Dearl all,

i'm trying to upgrade windows 8.1 to Windows 10 but at the end of the first installation phase, after copying the data, the update fails.

Actually, i think it could be a problem related to Windows Image Corruption caused by CSI Payload Corruption files, and DISM /RestoreHealth is unable to restore the image from WinSxS. I tried with an *install.wim* from an offical iso but it returned the famous "source problem", unfortunately it is the offical iso and my windows 8.1 is alredy update.

Here the error log of Windows 10 setup:

[setuperr.log](https://justpaste.it/5vue4)

There is also the *setupact.log* but it is a 64Mb txt file, so i can product it on some hosting server.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: System corruption wouldn’t block an upgrade to Windows 10

Comment: “I tried with an install.wim” - What method was that?

Comment: Using Dism to restore a corrupted image you can set the source to the install.wim from a windows 8.1 iso.
Ex. " DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:E\sources\install.wim /LimitAccess"

Actually  I could not find any solution.

Comment: I am aware of the method, but unware of the source problem, you used the media creation tool to attempt the upgrade?

Comment: There is no Media Creation Tool for Windows 8.1, just the iso downloaded by [https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows8ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows8ISO)  .

Comment: There actually is, but I was talking about, the Windows 10 Media Creation Tool.

Comment: Yes, i tried to upgrade to windows 10 with Media Creation Tool but it failed. I've also tried to create an iso with the tool but it failed too.
Moreover, I was thinking to my configuration due to the fact that windows 8.1 is installed on a GPT partition with UEFI mode, but i don't think it could be considered a problem.

Comment: Windows 10 supports GPT/UEFI